# Water behind ships much bluer than rest of ocean

Tags: color, water

On Wikipedia I have found the following image:

[image]
<sup>The Japan Maritime Self-Defense Force (JMSDF) destroyer JDS *Kongō* (DDG 173) sails in formation with other JMSDF ships and ships assigned to the USS *Kitty Hawk* Carrier Strike Group. [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:US_Navy_051115-N-8492C-125_The_Japan_Maritime_Self-Defense_Force_(JMSDF)_destroyer_JDS_Kongou_(DDG_173)_sails_in_formation_with_other_JMSDF_ships_and_ships_assigned_to_the_USS_Kitty_Hawk_Carrier_Strike_Group.jpg). Public domain image.</sup>

As you can see the water behind the ships is very neatly light blue, but the sky is much more colored like the rest of the ocean. Is this an effect like HDR or plain photoshop (post processing)?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> Is this an effect like HDR or plain photoshop (post processing)?

I'd say neither. The effect is natural. The ships' propellors churn the water quite a bit, causing the wake to become aerated. This is obvious from the white caps on the surface. But the aeration also extends below the surface. Aerated water like that tends to appear lighter shades of blue and blue-green.

The description of the file at Wikimedia Commons states that it was taken in late 2005 by US Navy Chief Photographer's Mate Todd Cichonowicz. While there might have been some post-processing, it was probably very little, considering the year the image was produced. Any HDR processing or other unconventional tricks would be required to be disclosed in the image's credit line per [U.S. Department of Defense policy](https://www.dimoc.mil/References/DoD-VI-Ethics/).

Comment: Navy policy for their photojournalists is that they are not even allowed to crop images under most circumstances (if the usage calls for a different aspect ratio, that task falls to the editor, not the photographer), so I highly doubt that they would release an image that had been overly processed to make the scene appear different that it more or less appeared to the eye at the time.

Comment: @MichaelC Yeah, it's a bit like several reporting or wire services, Nat Geo, etc., that only take JPEGs straight out of camera. I was wondering if this was for a PR photo, that perhaps it might have been sharpened, cropped, but that's about it.

Comment: The answers [on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-the-wake-behind-a-ship-seems-to-have-a-different-more-greenish-colour-compared-to-the-surrounding-seawater?share=1) attribute the coloration to phytoplankton, rather than simply to aeration of the water. Is there any way to choose one or the other explanation?

Comment: @Ruslan Both contribute. The aeration due to the prop wash oxygenates the plankton to a much higher O2 saturation level than they would otherwise be at in calm seas.

Comment: Very interesting answer and comments. I've spent quite some time digging through articles and images of ships in rainy or stormy conditions. For civilian ships I could only find one image where below the white mist you can see some turquoise like in the OP image. However for several military ships similar colors could be observed, so I assume it is really natural and just due to neglecting fuel efficiency and the environment over warlike conditions :-)

Comment: If the OP is referring to the wake, this is more of a physics question than a photography one. Just because someone takes a picture of a phenomenon shouldn't make it on-topic. Given that this is Photography SE, I was expecting a question along the lines of "Why is the water on the horizon bluer than the water close to the camera?"

Comment: @Acccumulation My initial question could be put in one statement as "is this achievable with a regular camera or is there editing going on?" and the answer could have been "no editing" but some additional interesting information was added as well - even some also related to photography, i.e. the fact that navy photographers are not allowed to edit their images.

Comment: This effect was one of the primary tools used in WW2 for spotting submerged submarines.

Comment: Water is blue because it is more effective at absorbing the other colors of visible light (or rather, blue wavelengths are more resistant to refraction/absorption loss); it's the same reason the sky is blue. But if you go deep enough even the blue wavelengths are absorbed eventually. The aeration makes the water less dense; and therefore less absorptive. The rest is just angle of incidence/reflection; as it is with any lighting.

Comment: There could also be a circular polarised involved...

Comment: @spikey_richie explain? What looks polarized to you?

Comment: Using a CP makes the whites pop, could be that the image was taken with a CP attached to the lens...

Comment: @spikey_richie polarizers aren't really about "making the whites pop". They kill reflections off surfaces normal to the polarization axis. Because the sun is coming from the upper right of the image (even though it's very diffuse because the cloud cover), and because the water on the right side is pretty shiny, that tells me there probably _wasn't_ a polarizer in play; or if there was, it wasn't aligned to reduce the reflections off the ocean. I'd add that if there was a polarizer tuned correctly, the long blue wake of the left ship would be even more visible further back.

Comment: @MichaelC, Re, "Navy policy...is that they are not even allowed to crop images." Not doubting you, but if that's how it actually is written, then what an absurd policy! Does somebody other than the journalist also decide where the journalist shall stand? In which exact direction the journalist shall point the camera? Which lens or zoom setting the journalist shall use? What shutter speed and what aperture? All of those things have just as much potential as cropping has to determine what is visible in the frame and what is not visible—just as much potential to change the meaning of the photo.

Comment: If the real policy is, "...submit only/all original files from the camera," then IMO that might make more sense. Military-style division of labor: You! We'll train you to operate a camera... You over there! You'll be trained to edit photos for publication...

Comment: @SolomonSlow I'll try to find the interview with a Photographer's mate were I read this. It was pretty much as stated above. No cropping of anything taken while on duty or with Navy equipment. Anything in the frame needs to be left in the frame. I guess it's possible the policy may also have to do with review of security issues regarding possible classified items appearing in an image that has been cropped by the photographer but of course would survive in any raw file and might slip through that review process unnoticed, but that was not mentioned in the article where I read this.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Here's [a link](https://www.dimoc.mil/References/DoD-VI-Ethics/) to a description of the actual policy. Note that it does allow for "judicious cropping that does not alter the context or meaning of the camera original." One can well imagine that at the unit level a CO would inform his Photographer's Mates this means "no cropping" in order to cover his own... ahem, career.

Comment: According to the policy, if any HDR or other "special" processing techniques were used, it would also have to be described as a "U.S. Navy photo illustration by Chief Photographer's Mate..." rather than as a "U.S. Navy photo by Chief Photographer's Mate..." in the credit line.

Answer (score 25):

Many navy ships intentionally inject air into their wake to obfuscate their sonar signature.  See [Prairie-Masker air system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prairie-Masker)

This added air gives the wake a light blue hue, and since the air bubbles are small they persist for quite some time.  I served on a US Navy ship and can attest that the color in this photo accurately depicts what our wake looked like.

Comment: Random tidbits of information are great, but this isn't an answer to the question. Downvoting, sorry.

Comment: Edited to make it more "answer-y".

Answer (score 3):

As [Scotbb answered](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/119940/39108), it is casued by aeration of the water.

Air is usually colourless and thus mixed with any coloured substance it makes the tone lighter, with respect to the ratio.

Propeller mixes the waters with air forming bubbles of various sizes, the bigger the bubble is the easier it gets to the surface and pops.

I expect the boats go on full throtle meaning higher mixing with air and forming a lot of micro bubbles that "float" in the water thanks to low buyoancy of the bubble and high viscosity of the surrounding water.

Comment: *Colorless* does not make any difference... it can't be added to anything. And air is not white, which would make a tone lighter. The bubbles/froth/wake are white because the air causes a very low density of water there, which causes the water to be much less absorptive of visible light; and therefore, they reflect more/all of the visible spectrum (angle of incidence/reflectance dependant).

Comment: The water density is given by temperature and salinity, mostly. The coroulesness of the air bubbles are the cause the water/bubble mixture absorbs less light but of same spectrum. Plus the round water/air interface reflects light as well. Was the air of some colour, it would shade the "tail" towards it's tone.

Answer (score 2):

The light blue stuff you're seeing are the *white* bubbles caused by the churn of the ships' propellers.

Water is blue; it absorbs other wavelengths of light to a greater extent than it absorbs blue wavelengths. If you place a long tank of water between you and a white light source, the light source will appear blue. The longer the tank, the more water there is between you and the light, thus the greater the absorption of light and the darker & bluer the water appears.

The water around the ships appears very dark blue because the light from the sky travels deep into the water and is mostly absorbed, leaving little to reflect back into the camera. Whereas the light hitting the white bubbles is mostly reflected into the camera after passing through mere metres of water; however, a little is absorbed. Thus the bubbles appear light blue instead of white.

If the ships were not causing bubbles but dragging bunches of white ribbons a few metres under the surface behind them, those ribbons would appear a similar light blue.

Answer (score 0):

Given the relatively low ambient light level (the scene is very overcast) it may also be a result of [bioluminescence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioluminescence).

Quote:
"Among the anecdotes of navigation by bioluminescence is one recounted by the Apollo 13 astronaut Jim Lovell, who as a navy pilot had found his way back to his aircraft carrier USS Shangri-La when his navigation systems failed. Turning off his cabin lights, he saw the glowing wake of the ship, and was able to fly to it and land safely."

Comment: From my own experience from scuba diving: that kind of biolumiscence is only visible when it is pretty dark.

Answer (score -2):

It's called bioluminescence from disturbed plankton, it's very common but more viable at night. It's like a giant blue or green Aaron pointing at them back of the ship.

Comment: Are you able to provide a source for this statement, in particular one that refutes the idea that it's just simple aeration of the water behind the ship?

Comment: bioluminescent plankton isn't visible during daylight though. And it's only visible in ships' wakes at night _sometimes_, depending on algal concentrations, temperature, conditions of the water column, etc. Whereas, the color-lightening effect in ships' wakes is always visible when ships are moving at speed. Even at night, when you don't see any bioluminescent glow, the water will appear a lighter shade of blue or green.